# Fine tuning Colpitts oscillator frequency with a varactor diode

Tags: transistors, rf, oscillator

I have tried the configuration in the image below but that doesn't seem to be responding very well. The frequency barely changes a few kHz if anything (Output frequency is around 10.5 MHz). Also, once I change the varactor control voltage, so does the oscillation amplitude, which is not a thing I want. What other possibilities are there available that would make sense on a design like this?

[image: Varactor diode at the base of the amplifier]

Answer (score 0):

You have put the varactor in the wrong place. It's a long way away from the tuning components, the inductor, 2.7 nF, 100 pF and 300 pF. All it changes is the 680 pF that's ideally 'infinite'.

Move the varactor to a better place, like logically across the inductor. Electrically of course you will need to decouple its bias from that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a common base Colpitts oscillator, which means the base is going to be a low impedance to ground at the frequency of interest, so that is not the place to connect your varactor. You would need to move it so it affects the resonant part of the circuit.

You also have to make sure you have the right capacitance to inductance ratio. With an 80 nH inductor the resonant capacitance for 10.5 MHz is 2872 pF, most of which is the 2.7 nF capacitor. You have to find out how much your varactor capacitance varies, and how much you want the frequency to vary, and size your total resonant capacitance and inductance so you will get the frequency variation you desire. The frequency change is going to depend on the ratio of the varactor capacitance to the total capacitance. If you're not getting enough range you would reduce the capacitance and increase the inductance.

You might also want to take the output from the emitter instead of the collector, as that should reduce the affect of loading on the frequency.